# Why or where were the 1000s of people who knew Jesus, why didn't they help

Tags: crucifixion, passion-of-jesus

In several passages of the bible Jesus healed, drove demons out, forgave, cured, and showed compassion to thousands of people.  He lifted a girl who was dead to her feet, and many more were supposedly dead that he brought back to life.  Behind all of these people were families, parents, brothers and sisters who were a testimony to his work.  They saw first hand what miracles he performed...yet no one spoke up for him?

Where were all of these people when he was being crucified...could not the thousands of people speak up or protest when he was handed over to Pilate.  I know these things were meant to happen but I am astonished that before he was crucified these same folks walked with him.  These same folks followed him and witnessed miracles first hand.  These folks had large families and I sure can beat word spread quickly.  Why didn't these folks start a battle to change things?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Unfortunately this question is not a good fit here as it can't really be answered without resorting to primarily opinion-based speculation - see [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-that-are-within-community-guidelines) or [What makes a good focused question?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/690/what-makes-a-good-focused-question) for more info.

Comment: It seems that no one understood Jesus' predictions of his death, so when he was killed his disciples thought the cause was lost.

Comment: So you're asking why all of those who believed in Jesus didn't start an armed revolt to rescue him from crucifixion?

Comment: See John 7:11-13

Comment: Why was that great article that was posted yesterday deleted in the comments?

Comment: This question was placed on hold. Seriously? Wouldn't it be better to just rephrase (edit) it a bit and make it less *prone* to receive opinion-based answers? I think that's quite achievable here. BTW behold! There is an answer already and it has far more quotes from scripture than the replier's own opinion. The question is a historical one and seems quite legitimate, on-topic to me. Its not ostracising group X or Y nor seeking personal advice nor being offensive. And there's even a disrespectful comment (voted up) that trivializes/ridicules the question by @Flimzy!

Comment: I'd like to be able to answer your question. You pointed a very pertinent symptom: why not a word written on all miracle recipients on the passion and crucifixion chapters of all 4 gospels? If not taking a stand on the scene, why not a word of a crowd sobbing somewhere or begging others not to commit such atrocities to their healer and Messiah or something? This symptom is quite telling of (i) the differences between external miracles and internal ones (ii) the limited purpose and range of the external ones and (iii) the role played by the Holy Spirit in witnessing and empowering believers.

Comment: ... that is the essence I see in your question, and that can be addressed with lots of quotes from scripture (or even tradition if this site cares more about it than scripture). How is the question then either off-topic, off-limits, or worth being put on hold?

Comment: @cnaak: It's easy to edit a question to be on topic. It's not easy to do so within the spirit of the question asked by the OP. I have no idea what objective question this OP is trying to get at (if there even is one), so editing to make it on-topic would be entirely inappropriate.

Comment: My comment neither trivializes nor ridicules the question. It simply points out the obvious conclusion which can be drawn by following the OP's apparent line of reasoning to its natural conclusion.

Comment: Thanks for replying, @Flimzy. I've *perceived* disrespect in your comment because you summed the OP up using two exaggerated terms, "armed revolt", that aren't found in the OP. There's no obvious conclusion at one's reach, but there is an *opportunity to make a positive and sober approach, even to an ill-formatted question, to make the best out of it*. Thus, in good spirit we could read the OP in many positive ways: why the omission of those people benefited by Jesus? / why the apparent ingratitude or indifference? / does healing really change a person spiritually? and so on...

Comment: @cnaak: How could 1000s of people "help" a condemned criminal? In modern times, they could petition the governor for a stay or pardon of execution. They could engage media, to try to bring public shame and/or political pressure to those with power over the sentence. They could form picket lines or do engage in a riot. They could attempt a revolt. The peaceful options didn't exist at the time of Jesus' execution. Thus, to me, it seems obvious that the only way "1000s of people who knew Jesus" could "help" would be armed revolt.

Comment: @Flimzy - Maybe that was one way, but the other is simply speaking, so I'm not sure why my question was closed / put on hold.  I'm not even sure why many AWESOME great comments including a fabulous link was deleted in these comments but its certainly not welcoming.  The answers and the comments truly show that people DID want to answer this question (in fact someone has attempted to), so I will live with that.

Comment: Hello @Flimzy, this is a much nicer (and clearer) way to put it! If this was your first post we wouldn't be having this discussions. Sure the OP is not "quite there" in terms of the quality standards set forth for this site. It could have been edited to "Are there evidences of why the gospels are silent about those healed by Jesus during His passion"? Or something along these lines (this is what I get from the question description). My very best regards!

Comment: But on most of the stackexchange sites, why couldn't this merely be edited to what you have suggested rather than close it?  Wasn't it enough that someone took time out of their own day to answer it?

Comment: Hello @JonH, that's my point exactly all along (I was a lot more excited about this website until I've seen how your question has been handled). And yes, I do want to give an answer to your question. May I ask you to try posting it again with a different wording (please check my other comments). Thank you in advance! If you conform to the guidelines, I believe your new question will be welcomed!

Comment: @JonH: What makes you think they didn't speak up? I think it's pretty obvious from scripture (as well as human nature) that they DID.

Comment: @JonH: Feel free to edit the question now. Just because it's on hold now doesn't mean it can't be re-opened if it's cleaned up to fit within site guidelines.

Comment: So maybe that could of been your answer with why you believe that to be your answer rather than close the question??

Comment: Flimzy I never said I would post it again, I am not a noob to the system so I don't really need to be taught how to use it.  Can you smile today?

Comment: @Flimzy: I profited from your correction. Thank you for the clarification. In fact, I'm the noob—10 days old on Christianity.SE.

Comment: @cnaak: Welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Roman rule was very harsh, they had very little regard for the lives of the Jews, as is indicated by their crucifying two thieves along with Jesus.

> Luke 23:33 NKJV  And when they had come to the place called Calvary, there they crucified Him, and the criminals, one on the right hand and the other on the left.

Even the Apostles were afraid as indicated by Peter's denial.

> Mark 14:72 NKJV  A second time the rooster crowed. Then Peter called to mind the word that Jesus had said to him, "Before the rooster crows twice, you will deny Me three times." And when he thought about it, he wept.

Then just as today standing up for Jesus can make you a Martyr under a repressive Regime. To fear death is a basic human fear, and it is a characteristic of Christianity to lose that fear. However they did not know Jesus had power over death until he arose.

> Matthew 10:28 NKJV  And do not fear those who kill the body but cannot kill the soul. But rather fear Him who is able to destroy both soul and body in hell.
>
> Luke 24:1 through 7  Now on the first day of the week, very early in the morning, they, and certain other women with them, came to the tomb bringing the spices which they had prepared. 2  But they found the stone rolled away from the tomb. 3  Then they went in and did not find the body of the Lord Jesus. 4  And it happened, as they were greatly perplexed about this, that behold, two men stood by them in shining garments. 5  Then, as they were afraid and bowed their faces to the earth, they said to them, "Why do you seek the living among the dead? 6  He is not here, but is risen! Remember how He spoke to you when He was still in Galilee, 7  saying, 'The Son of Man must be delivered into the hands of sinful men, and be crucified, and the third day rise again.' "

That is one of the great things about salvation in that it is victory over death. And with it comes eternal life.

> John 10:28 NKJV  And I give them eternal life, and they shall never perish; neither shall anyone snatch them out of My hand.
>
> John 17:1 through 3 NKJV  Jesus spoke these words, lifted up His eyes to heaven, and said: "Father, the hour has come. Glorify Your Son, that Your Son also may glorify You,
> 2  as You have given Him authority over all flesh, that He should give eternal life to as many as You have given Him. 3  And this is eternal life, that they may know You, the only true God, and Jesus Christ whom You have sent.